# Transpose whole dataframe into one row dataframe- (or transposing each row of data.table and column binding)

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, reshape2

I have tried to transform `my_dataset` with the help of library reshape & `data.table` in order to achieve the `result.dataset` but haven't been successful as yet.

I have a data table `my_dataset` that looks like this :-

```
A    X     Count
id1  b     1
id1  c     2
```

And  I want to have the `result.dataset` that should look like this :-

```
 A   X1  Count1  X2  Count2  
 id1  b    1      c    2
```

It would be great if anyone could help me to get the `result.dataset` as above, preferably by using `reshape` or `data.table` (or both lib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dt <- read.table(text = 'A    X     Count
id1  b     1
id1  c     2',header=T)
a <- aggregate(.~A, dt, paste, collapse=",")
library(splitstackshape)
result <- concat.split.multiple(data = a, split.cols = c("X","Count"), seps = ",")
```

output:

```
> result
A X_1 X_2 Count_1 Count_2
1: id1   b   c       1       2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that is using only `reshape2` (trying to stick to the suggested packages). It starts by adding a column `rep`, that allows one to call `dcast`.

```
require(reshape2)

#adding rep
my_dataset$rep = unlist(tapply(my_dataset$A, my_dataset$A, function(x)1:length(x)))

#cast at work
C1 = dcast(my_dataset, A ~ paste('X',rep, sep=''), value.var='X')
C2 = dcast(my_dataset, A ~ paste('Count',rep, sep=''), value.var='Count')

result.dataset = cbind(C1, C2[,-1])
```

The columns will not be in the same order as your example though.

Answer (score 1):

We can aggregate the rows and use `cSplit` to split them.

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)

dat2 <- setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ","), by = A]

cols <- c(names(dat[, 1]), paste(names(dat[, -1]), 
                                 rep(1:nrow(dat), each = nrow(dat), 
                                 sep = "_"))

cSplit(dat2, splitCols = names(dat[, -1]))[, cols, with = FALSE]
#      A X_1 Count_1 X_2 Count_2
# 1: id1   b       1   c       2
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "A    X     Count
id1  b     1
id1  c     2",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: You are genius, this is really very helpful; but do we also have some workaround with which we can automatically re-order the result dataset as it is in my post; Like using chain operations from data.table library. Thanks again :)

Comment: @MukundJha Please see my update. I prepared a vector called `cols` that contains the column names with the right order in `dat2`. This may not be elegant, but I think it will work even you have lots of columns to split. In addition, `splitCols = names(dat[, -1])` allows us to split the columns without specifying the column names.